# Does it make sense to self check for null in Java

Tags: java, coding-style, null, nullpointerexception

I often see java SourceCode where a null as value for a method or constructor is not allowed. A Typical implementation of this looks like

```
public void someMethod(Object someObject){

    if(someObject == null) throw new NullPointerException()

    someObject.aMethodCall()

}
```

I see no sense for myself in that at all, because if I attempt to call a Method on a nullPointer the `NullPointerException` is thrown anyways. I would see a sense if this method would throw an IllegalArgumentException or some other custom-made exception. Can someone clearify , why this check seems to makes sense (as I see it very often I'm assuming, that there has to be sense behind that), or why it's complete nonsense

Comment: This is useless if the correct behaviour is to null pointer (in fact it's worse since the check takes a small amount of time).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280/passing-null-to-a-method I prefer assertions for parameter goodness checking, just like preconditions are used in Ada.

Comment: Explicit null-checks are as cheap as implicit null-checks after JIT'ing, so I wouldn't worry about performance here.

Comment: I'd argue it's the wrong exception to be thrown.  If anything, you should throw an [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) as you are enforcing the precondition of what a method needs *before* anything is done.  That's *really* what you want to do.  You are right, *this* exception is the *wrong* exception, but it doesn't mean you shouldn't perform the check *or throw the proper exception*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you posted makes absolutely no sense at all. It looks like a strong case of [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Most likely, somebody implemented a useful test to check for pre-conditions once and somebody else adapted the test to look like this.

Answer (score 6):

There is a corner case where something like that would make sense.  If you don't use someObject immediately short-circuiting the error case to the start of the function can be useful.

```
public void someMethod(Object someObject){

    if(someObject == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    expensiveOperationNotUsingSomeObject();

    someObject.aMethodCall();
}
```

Comment: +1 a check and explicit throw *can* be useful. Think fail fast, fail early.

Answer (score 5):

No, that doesn't make much sense as it stands, but only because throwing an NPE doesn't add any useful info.

You could make the error nicer by throwing (for example) an IllegalStateException:

```
if (someObject == null) throw new IllegalStateException("someObject was null");
```

But that doesn't add a great deal of value either - other than being specific about what is null (which can be useful in more complex methods)

Comment: And the possible exception should be declared in the `throws` clause and documented.

Answer (score 5):

Of course you want to check for null.  This is a pre-condition for your method, part of its contract with clients.  If your method cannot accept null input, you need to enforce that.

The choice of exception could be better.  I usually go with an `IllegalArgumentException`.

If it's the brevity of the method that bothers you, I have to say I agree.  No new info there.

Comment: I don't believe `IllegalArgumentException` is better choice. `NPE` is more specific. Also you can consult item 60 of Effective Java about it.

Comment: I'll give it a look, but I don't know if I agree.  The message in IAE can make it clear enough.  It can also flag other conditions (e.g. String that can be neither blank nor null).  Your interpretation is very narrow, but correct for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on who is responsible to recover from this situation. If it's the caller, throw a NPE. If it's the called method, test for `null` and do anything that is necessary to resolve the situation.

**Edit:** Don't throw a NPE explicitly but just let it bubble up. Sorry for the vague wording.

Comment: But in the case the example the OP gave, it is clear that the method itself isn't recovering from the exception...

Comment: True, but I took this only as a MWE, not as real code.

Comment: Throwing unchecked exception is bad programming practice...

Comment: @Alex Checked exceptions should be thrown when there's a reasonable expectation that the caller can handle it somehow, etc. Certainly not because of programming errors. Or do you really think that we should make `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` checked too?

Comment: @Voo : Unchecked exceptions generally represent errors in your code. For example the ArrayOutOfBoundsException means that you access the array in a wrong way and this "program error" should be fixed. The normal execution of a program should not normally encounter unchecked exceptions...

Comment: @VOo : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html -> "Generally speaking, do not throw a RuntimeException or create a subclass of RuntimeException simply because you don't want to be bothered with specifying the exceptions your methods can throw."

Comment: @Alex And giving an illegal parameter to an exception is not a programming error?

Comment: @Voo Yes it is! But best practice and common sense tells that methods should throw Cheked exceptions (define custom exception that encapsulate your program bad use-cases) and these exception should be handled by the caller. Unchecked exception will only be visible at runtime and they can cause a lot of pain after deployments. This is not the case with test cases of course...

Comment: @Alex But throwing a checked exception for illegal input would make the code rather unwieldy and shouldn't happen in valid code (and I'd hope someone would run the code at least once before it being deployed!). And there's precedence for this in the standard library, like `Hashtable.put` for example. Seems to me this would lead to patterns like `catch (SomeException e) { // can never happen! }` which I don't like either.

Comment: @Voo : There are situations where throwing unchecked is the only way to go... This is not one of them, or they should not be used unless you have well defined interfaces, with strong contracts, like the Map interface. You cannot create code that throws runtime exceptions everywhere... It is just unmaintainable...

Comment: @Alex Well I assume that the function is clearly documented like `Object someObject <description>. Must not be null.` and imo it should also clearly state what RuntimeExceptions are thrown under which circumstances - basically how `Hashtable.put` handles it. Making something a checked exception should never be a replacement for good documentation, those two things are there for different reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The situation you describe may be useful under one of the following assumptions:

1.) If you have to perform some operations which are either costly or do change some global state prior to the execution `someObject.aMethodCall()` you can prevent rollback code and waste of execution cycles.

2.) If `someObject` is stored within a data structure, you may create a possible pitfall if at some later point the data is retrieved from the data structure. I think, I remember some classes in the java collection framework, which throw rather a NPE than allowing a null into the storage structure.

Comment: An example from the Java collections: Older versions of an empty `TreeSet` allowed `null` to be added, only to throw a NPE when any second element was to be added. The current version of `TreeSet.add` explicitly checks for `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Personally the reason why I'd never throw a NullPointerException as part of a public API method is because it makes it much harder for the programmer to distinguish between a programming error on their side and a bug in my code (ie did I deliberately allow the NPE to be thrown or not?).

Throwing a different exception makes the intention much clearer and also helps the programmer to find out what's wrong easier. So I'd go with `IllegalArgumentException` there.

If it's some internal method? I'd use assertions or just let it crash. No sense in explicitly throwing a NPE imo.

Answer (score 0):

I think doing this type of check makes sense if a method does processing which takes a lot of time or is hard to undo before it actually triggers the NPE. In the example given I don't think it makes actual sense.

On the other hand: using assert or throwing a more specific exception like IllegalArgumentException might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

In C# exists an ArgumentNullException. This exception takes the name of the argument in the constructor. So the caller could see, which argument maybe is illicity NULL.
The IllegalArgumentException is almost the Java-equivalent to that.